# How to keep whole table visible when all checkboxes get unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I play around with checkboxes it's all good and sorting/filtering is working fine, until I uncheck everything. Then all data disappears.

I would like all data to become visible when checkboxes are unchecked. How can I achieve that?

Btw. The code I am using is not mine. I'm a noob in JS/JQuery.

I'll greatly appreciate your help.

I've searched for solutions and tried dozens of options, but the noob I am, I could not figure it out.

Everything can be found on Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kXNAg/ .

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
var checkedValues = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();

$("tbody tr").hide();
for (var i = 0; i < checkedValues.length; i++) {
    $("tbody tr td:contains('" + checkedValues[i] + "')").parent("tr").show();
}
});
```

Actual: You click checkboxes, sort the table , all is good, then you uncheck everything and data is hidden.

Expected: Like above but when you uncheck boxes then table data is all visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if nothing is checked you need to go back to default state:

```js
if(checkedValues.length === 0) return $("tbody tr").show();
```

checkout here: http://jsfiddle.net/gmeo64dx/

Comment: Thank you :) Now iit's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of your `checkedValues` array and react accordingly

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
  var checkedValues = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  if (!checkedValues.length) {
    $("tbody tr").show();
  } else {
    $("tbody tr").hide();
    for (var i = 0; i < checkedValues.length; i++) {
      $("tbody tr td:contains('" + checkedValues[i] + "')").parent("tr").show();
    }
  }
});
```